# Visual Studio 2013 Dataset Designer refresh relations

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dataset

I have an application with a dataset linked to an sql server database.  I have updated some of the names or foreign keys and primary keys in the sql server.  How do I make those changes translate to the data set.  For example, I had a primary key called fk_temsempl_xxxxx.  I changed it to fk_temsempl on the sql database.  How do I get that change to show in the dataset designer in visual studio?

I have tried running custom tool by right clicking on the dataset and clicking run custom tool.  That didnt work.  I tried configuring the table adapter of one of the tables where a change occured, but the name of the relation didnt change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually just right click the relation and choose `Edit Relation...` or double click on the line (when the mouse cursor changes from arrow to drag symbol) but I honestly wouldn't bother; you'll then have further refactoring to do in the code anywhere the relation is used, and it can be heavily used by visual designers.

You also get the problem that VS may not help you with the refactoring: in data binding scenarios most things that can be a source of data can also be a collection of multiple things that can be a valid `DataSource`. They then rely on a string `DataMember` to determine which of the collections of data in the data source should be used for the data.

For example, when a bindingsource is bound to list a `DataTable`, the `bindingsource.DataSource` property might be the `DataSet` object that contains the `DataTable, and the`bindingsource.DataMember`is a string of "YOUR_TABLE_NAME". the BindingSource might not be bound as`myBindignSource.DataSource = myDataSet.MyDataTable`. Refactoring inside strings involves a find and replace

DataRelations in a DataSet are created from foreign keys as they were discovered when the relevant table(s) were added to the dataset but it is important to note that, like DataTables and everything else, they are NOTHING to do with the database schema objects at all - they aren't permanently associated with them, the dataset entities are just set up looking something like the database objects when they (dataset entities) are first created. DataTables are created from only those columns selected, and whatever .NET datatypes closely resemble the types output by the query. For a table of:

```
Person
------
Name VARCHAR(50)
SSN INTEGER
Birthdate DATE
```

If you created the table with `SELECT * FROM Person` you'd get a datatable with `Name (string), SSN (int), Birthdate (datetime)` but if you made a new datatable in the dataset based on `SELECT LEFT(Name, 1) as Initial, PADLEFT(SSN, 20) as PadSSN, DATEDIFF(day, Birthdate, NOW()) as AgeDays FROM Person` then you'd get a datatable of `Initial (string), PadSSN (string), AgeDays (int)` - i.e. the datatable looks nothing like the db table. This concept of disconnection between dataset and db is pervasive, and really the only things that relate in any way to the database are the properties that specify which DB table/column a particular DataTable/DataColumn relates to for purposes of loading/saving data. Your `Person.Name` datacolumn can be renamed to `Blahblah`, but it will still have a `.SourceColumn` property that is set to `"Name"` - that's how the mapping between dataset and db works; dataset is predominantly completely independent of the db. Renaming a DB column would require a change to the `SourceColumn` property only

DataRelations don't even have this notion of linking to the parent relation in the database; there's no `SourceRelation` or `SourceFK` proeprty because there is no need to. They're set up with the same rules and a generated name all based on the rules of the FK, but then they function independently and only within the dataset. If you rename or even remove an FK from the db the dataset will carry on working in the same restricted way it always did; adding a datarow to a child table when no aprent row exists for it will throw an exception - none of it anything to do with the FK in the db, and the `DataRelation` can have different rules to the FK (e.g it can cascade deletes when the FK is NOACTION) or even different columns. You can have more or fewer DataRelations than the DB has FKs

---

Run Custom Tool is not a "contact the DB and see what changes have occurred there and replicate them into the dataset", it is a "turn the XSD that describes the dataset into a bunch of C# classes that implement strongly typed dataset/table/relation/column etc objects". Any time you change the XSD by making an edit in the visual designer and hit save, the custom tool is run. If you edit the XSD directly in a text editor you may need to run it manually to have your changes reflected in c# classes

---

Reconfiguring a tableadapter probably won't do anything to the relations either; its solely concerned with changing the datatable and tableadapter. If you really want to refresh the relations, delete the datatable from the set and recreate it. Be prepared for a potentially significant mop up/refactoring of code

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation.  I am seeing that mop up.  I wish Microsoft would update their dataset designer.  It needs a major overhaul.  They could do so much better.  I really like the dataset designer because I can add queries to tables with parameters to limit the data selected.  It makes it easy.  I just with the designer was way more functional.